# How to display an initial value in a WPF ComboBox

Tags: wpf, combobox

XAML Code

```
<ComboBox Height="23" Margin="69,105,111,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding StoreTypeTable}" DisplayMemberPath="StoreTypeName" SelectedValuePath="StoreTypeName"  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectedIndex="0"/>
```

C# Code:

My Class:

```
class StoreTypes:nuClass
{
   private WSOntsu.ServiceSoapClient _WS;
   private WSOntsu.OSM007StoreType _DS;

   public StoreTypes()
   {
        try
        {
            _WS = new WpfOntsu.WSOntsu.ServiceSoapClient();
            _DS = _WS.lstStoreType();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            bResult = false;
            sResult = e.Message;
        }
             bResult = _DS.Osm007getStoreType.Rows.Count > 0;
   }

    public DataTable StoreTypeTable
    {
        get { return _DS.Osm007getStoreType; }
    }

}
```

My Page load:

```
StoreTypes _ST = new StoreTypes();
comboBox1.ItemsSource = _ST.StoreTypeTable.Rows;
```

How to display combo initial value when page is loading?

plz help me.

Comment: We're going to need some more details I'm afraid. Try posting us your sample xaml file or csharp file which is loading the list

Comment: Agreed, we definately need more info. Show us some code, and explain exactly what you expect it to do, and what you see instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your request is very unclear. If you want to select the first value in the ComboBox, you can do something like:

```
StoreTypes _ST = new StoreTypes();
comboBox1.ItemsSource = _ST.StoreTypeTable.Rows;

if (comboBox1.Items.Count > 0)
{
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

If that's not what you want, please edit your question.